# Thread is not Stopping/Interrupting

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this code sample

```
    public static class BlinkMe extends Thread {

        int counter = 0;
        protected boolean stop = true;

        public void run() {
            while (stop) {
                counter++;


                if (counter % 2 == 0) {

                    jLabel4.setVisible(true);
                    jLabel7.setVisible(true);
                    jLabel8.setVisible(true);
                    counter = 0;

                } else {

                    jLabel4.setVisible(false);
                    jLabel7.setVisible(false);
                    jLabel8.setVisible(false);
                    if (jButton4.isEnabled() == false) {
                        stop = false;
                        jLabel4.setVisible(true);
                        jLabel7.setVisible(true);
                        jLabel8.setVisible(true);
                        if (jButton2.isEnabled() == false) {
                            stop = true;
                            jButton2.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

I need to stop this `Thread` when I press my Stop Button...
Here's the code I'm using for the Button's function but it is not working. ***The `Thread` is not working at ll*

Here is the Button's function

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    BlinkMe b=new BlinkMe();
    b.stop(); //here I have even used b.interrupt(); but doesn't stop the
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: Try to start it after creation `BlinkMe b=new BlinkMe(); b.start();`

Comment: You can modify GUI-Elemets only from the Main Thread. You cannot update them from a different thread. Have a look at the Timer class or at SwingUtils.invokeLater

Comment: btw, interrupt() doesn't stop a thread by itself. By default it does nothing. You should implement that method if you want to use it

Comment: You need to read the [documentation for Thread.stop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--) *immediately.*  Short version:  Don’t use Thread.stop(), ever.  Also, you are modifying Swing components outside of the AWT event dispatch thread;  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/.

Comment: API documentation for stop: _Deprecated. This method is inherently unsafe ... Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from its run method ... if the variable indicates that it is to stop running._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many things wrong in this code.

1. you're accessing Swing components from a background thread. That's forbidden. Only the event dispatch thread is allowed to access Swing components
2. You're trying to stop() a thread, although this method is deprecaed and should never, ever be used, as the documentation explains
3. Instead of stopping the actual thread, you create a new instance of that thread class, and call stop() on that new instance.
4. You "blink" without any delay between the blink.
5. Your thread uses a stop variable, but this variable is never modified anywhere. Even if it was, it's not volatile, so you have a big chance of not seeing the modification, and thus not stopping the thread.

Read the Swing tutorial abount concurrency. And use a Swing Timer, which is designed to do that kind of thing, safely.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new thread in actionPerformed and trying to stop the same, which was not started so far. Try calling stop in actual thread.

Answer (score -1):

The initial value of your stop is "true". This means that when the thread starts, the run method executes but will not execute the while block because the condition will result to false right away.

First, you need to change your while loop into like this:

```
while(!stop) { /* the rest of your code */ }
```

Next, you need to create a method in your BlinkMe thread that would allow other objects in your program that would make it stop. The method would look something like this:

```
public void stopBlinking() {
    stop = true;
}
```

Calling the above method will stop the infinite loop in the run method.

I don't think you will see a blinking effect when you run your program. It is because the loop executes very fast. I suggest you put a Thread.sleep(1000) somewhere in the loop so that there is time to reflect the blink effect visually.

Comment: stop is true, and the loop is `while (stop)`. So the loop will execute. (The variable is badly named, but that's another story). And changing the value of stop won't work (or at least, is not guaranteed to work) if it's not volatile